# Firefox extensions: Self hosted and AMO

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Recently the possibility was added to choose if my extension should be listed on AMO or if I want to distribute it by myself.

My Question: If I go the self-hosted route and add an updateUrl to my manifest, will the extension nevertheless be updated by AMO if I upload a newer version that gets through review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it is mentioned in AMO

**On your own:** Your submission will be immediately signed for self-distribution. Updates should be handled by you via an updateURL or external application updates.

So you will take care of the updates of your add-on and AMO doesn't deal with it. However the updates will get through the review on AMO.

Comment: To add clarification.  You will have to manually update the manifest pointed to by updateUrl with the new version.  Also, HTTPS is only supported.